# How to convert string format of time type field in DolphinDB c ++ API

Tags: c++, sql, dolphindb

Suppose I have the following table,

```
t=table(1..3 as id,(now() - 2)..now() as ts)
share(t, `sharedT);
```

I query the value of the ts column in the API, the code is as follows,

```
DBConnection conn;
TableSP table = conn.run("select * from sharedT");
ConstantSP col1=table->getcolumn(1);
cout<<col1->getString(0)<<endl;
```

The displayed result is like 2020.02.20T01:44:58, but the format I want to get is 02/20/2020T01:44:58.
How to convert this is more convenient？

Answer (score 0):

It is better off to format the datetime column on the server end.

```
DBConnection conn;
TableSP table = conn.run("select id,format(ts,'MM/dd/yyyyTHH:mm:ss') as ts from sharedT");
ConstantSP col1=table->getcolumn(1);
cout<<col1->getString(0)<<endl;
```